# png.file at the top center of Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I create my Shiny app and I just add one png.file at the top of Shiny app and I would like to see it in center position.
I use the code:

```
img(src = "logo.png", align = "center")
```

or

```
img(src = "logo.png", align = "centre")
```

but it does not work.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're after: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/555

Sorry it's so late!

AB

> The align attribute of  is not what you need. It is a different
>   thing (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp). You can use
>   style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" to
>   center an image. Or div(img(...), style="text-align: center;").